# Contract failing at updateUserTask

Tags: solidity, remix

The contract intends to create a set of tasks dynamically, eg: tasks can be added(There is no need for deletion.) 
Some tasks will be related by a variable within the struct called smart contract
Each of this task should be assigned to every user that calls update. 
Finally The smart contract will have a function to iterate through all the addresses that have called update.

So far I have managed to be able to create tasks on command, and I can edit variables. I how ever have not managed to set it up so that each user owns its own array. Currently when I call get task, I just get the latest one created so I messes up somewhere else too, though I cant seem to find where.

So I have to be missing something. Any pointers are appreciated.

```
/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions".
 */
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Owned {

    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

  /// @notice modifies any function it gets attached to, only allows the owner of the smart contract to execute the function
  modifier onlyOwner(){
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }
}

///The contract intends to create a set of tasks dynamically, eg: tasks can be added(There is no need for deletion.) 
///Some tasks will be related by a variable within the struct called smart contract
///Each of this task should be assigned to every user that calls update. 
///Finally The smart contract will have a function to iterate through all the addresses that have called update.

contract taskListContract is Owned {
    address public receiver;

    struct task {
        string iName;
        uint16 taskId;
        address smartContract;
        bool iValue;
    }

    uint taskCount;
    mapping(address => task) taskList;
    task[] taskArray;

    function addTask(string name, uint16 id, address code) external onlyOwner{
        receiver = msg.sender;
        task memory tasknew = task(name, id ,code, false);
        taskList[receiver] = tasknew;
        taskArray.push(tasknew);
        taskCount++;
    }


    function updateUserTask(bool _value) public{
        task storage individualUser =taskList[receiver];
        individualUser.iValue = _value;
    }

/**                 TODO 
 *  update all the users at the same time
 *  0xe3b819b9d1356bbbce0000ee1251d04d8bce60a1
 *
 *  function updateAllUserTasks() public{
 *      receiver = msg.sender;
 *      userTaskList(receiver)
 *
 *  }
 */

    function countItemList() public constant returns (uint count)  {     
        return taskCount;
    }

    function removeTask() external onlyOwner {
        delete taskList[msg.sender];
        taskCount--;
    }

    function getTask() public constant returns (string iName, bool iValue, uint count)  {   
        return (taskList[msg.sender].iName, taskList[msg.sender].iValue, taskCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have a task array per user, you'll have to change your mapping to

```
mapping(address => task[]) taskList;
```

In this case, you don't need the workaround with `receiver`.